# what does "missing FROM-clause entry for table" mean?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

How would I write a SQL query so that `Group.where("blob.item.id = ?", self.id)` returns the correct associations? That line gives this error: `ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  missing FROM-clause entry for table "item"`.

The SQL is written in a method on `Item`, and when I call it, I do so like `Item.first.groups`:

```
Class Item
 has_many :wanted_trades, class_name: "Trade", foreign_key: :share_id
 has_many :shares

 def trades
  Trade.where("share.item.id = ?", self.id)
 end
end


Class Trade
 belongs_to :wanted_share, class_name: "Share"
end

Class Share
 belongs_to :item
end
```

If I do `Trade.joins(wanted_share: :item).where("wanted_share.item.id = ?", self.id)` I get the same error, just with a longer SQL lookup.

Comment: Where is `wanted_share` defined? Is it a table you forgot to include?

Comment: You mentioned `belongs_to :wanted_share` but there is no model named `WantedShare`.

Comment: @JagdeepSingh it's an association name

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using `joins`? `ActiveRecord` doesn't allow you to use table prefixes in the `where` method as far as I know, so you'll either have to use `joins`:

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#joining-tables

or write the raw sql, which will allow you to use your table prefix:

`sql = "SELECT * from ..."
records_array = ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute(sql)`

Comment: the part i don't understand is joining multiple tables. my method is inside Item, but queries Trade. it *seems* to me that, since the odd one out is Share, i'd join that. but no.

Comment: `Trade.joins("INNER JOIN wanted_shares ON wanted_shares.item_id = items.id")` seems like it'd work given the above associations, but instead i just get an error that says `relation "wanted_share" does not exist`

Comment: That's because you don't have an actual table called wanted_shares. You only have the alias in Rails. You would have to query by the share_id

Comment: i'm not sure i follow. i want to query the `belongs_to` of a `belongs_to` of a `has_many`. there has to be some way of doing this without making a new table

Comment: You can do `Trade.wanted_shares.joins(:items)......`, but you can't do `'wanted_shares.item_id'` because the former builds the SQL that performs the join, the latter is inserted into the query, and since the table `wanted_shares` isn't actually a table in your database, it errors out.